# Connect to docker mysql with golang

Tags: mysql, docker, go

Running docker mysql

`docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:5.7`

[mysql docker running container][1]

Go Code:

package main

```
import (
"database/sql"

_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(172.17.0.2:3306)/test-db")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer db.Close()
err = db.ping()
if err != nil {
   log.Print(err)
}
```

ping is throwing up ETIMEDOUT . The IP is correct is container IP.

Comment: Have you checked the port? What's the external (exposed) port number for the container?

Comment: Why don't you publish the port using `-p` flag? It would be a lot simpler `docker run — name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.7` and then use `db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(localhost:3306)/test-db")`

Comment: Are you running this code from the host or another container; if another container, how are you launching the two containers?  That IP address will change whenever you redeploy this container stack and looking it up at all, much less hard-coding it, isn’t generally a best practice.

Comment: Have you noticed whether MySQL server is started or not? Because running the container doesn't have the meaning that the application in the container is started.

Answer (score 1):

It must expose a port for docker internal IP however IP can be changed on every restart. To map a port to the localhost you can use the flag `-p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306`

To specify IP for docker container you can create your own user-defined virtual network and bind IP on this network when starting your containers.

```
docker network create --subnet=192.168.101.0/24 test
docker run -d --name db1 --network test --ip=192.168.101.10 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 mysql:5.7
mysql -h 192.168.101.10 -uroot -p12345
```

Also, be sure MySQL is started. You can check the status with `docker ps` and logs with `docker logs db1`. Where `db1` the name specified with the flag `--name`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the MySQL port using the docker `-p` port e.g.

```
docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -p 33060:3306 -d mysql:5.7
```

Then the standard MySQL application port of 3306 will be mapped on your host IP to the port 33060. Then use that IP and port in your golang app configuration.

Also as @Adrian pointed out, wait for the MySql container to boot-up fully. You can watch it's log via `docker logs -f <CONTAINER_UD>`. Once you see it listening on it's local port of 3306, your application should be able to connect.

Comment: The port part should be `-p 3306:3306` (removing un-needed trailing 0)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to work on a Docker MySQL but to work on a Docker that is Linux based with mysql + go on it.

Created a Docker image which is a combination of Ubuntu 18.04 + Mysql Server 5.7 + Golang 1.13. Available on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/vinujoseph1/ubuntu-mysql-server-golang).

Pull the image and run it using the following command:-

Once the image is pulled, you can start the mysql server with the following command -

> /etc/init.d/mysql start